# How to put check-boxes next to data displayed from the database - PHP, SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I am displaying some data from my database, and I wnat to be able to put checkboxes next to each record displayed. 
Afther that I want the user to be able to submit their selection and that will then delete the selected records. 
I googled a lot of things, but could not make anything work. I'm looking for smething simple. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
//include('conn.php');
$con=mysqli_connect();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
header('location:login.php');
}
//
?>
<?php

if (!$link = mysql_connect()) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db()) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

$villageId = $_GET['village']; 
$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];



$sql ="SELECT * 
FROM favourites
INNER JOIN attractions ON favourites.AttractionID = attractions.AttractionID
INNER JOIN customer ON favourites.ID = customer.ID
WHERE favourites.ID = '$ID' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}








while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row['Name'] ;



}









 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}



mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simple add checkbox near data output:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo " <input type='checkbox' value='".$row['id']."' /> ".$row['Name'];
}
```

As I understand you need this:

1. Output some rows `data - checkbox`
2. User will select some checkboxes and data, connected with that checkboxes will be deleted from the database.
3. Delete deleted data from the page.

How to achieve this?

You need html code below to ahieve what you want (+ you need some javascript, I will tell about it later):

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <div id='1'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='1' />Row 1</div>
    <div id='2'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='2' />Row 1</div>
    <div id='3'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='3' />Row 1</div>
</form>
```

Look the example of that code + serialize form on link `onclick` handler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/575VS/4/).

Generate same output in PHP:

```
// execute query
echo "<form id='myForm'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div id='".$row['id']."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['id']."' /> ".$row['Name']." </div>";
}
echo "<a href='#' id='delete'>Delete</a>";
echo "</form>";
```

So, now we made 1st item of our list and half of 2nd (serialize form).

How to achieve another half of 2nd item. We have to create php script where we will delete rows from the database.

`deleteScript.php` script:

```
// connect to the base
foreach($id in $_POST['data']) {
    $query = "delete from `favourites` where `id` = ".$id;
    // execute your query
}
```

Script ready. Now you have to send request from our page to this script. Use ajax request for it:

```
$("#delete").on('click', function () {
    var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
    if(data != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "deleteScript.php",
            data: data
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("select some checkboxes");
    }
});
```

This javascript code works with previous html code

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/575VS/6/).

Now, 1st and 2nd items of our list done.

Let's delete deleted items from our page immidiately (3rd item of todo list):

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function()
{
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("div#"+id).remove();
});
```

You can test this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/575VS/18/)

That example was created to show you, that my approach works. But! You have to remove div's only if request had been sent successfully. So you have to edit `$.ajax` `success` handler. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/575VS/19/) for it.

So, now we made all items from our list.

Final example here: http://jsfiddle.net/575VS/18/

You have to copy past it just to your files :)

Hope, this will help.

**Note**, that you can get ajax-request response.

```
$.ajax({
   //some properties
   success: function(data) {
       //response will be in data variable
   }
});
```

If you want to redirect page right after deleting selected rows in database use this code:

```
if(data != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteScript.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            window.location.replace("new link here");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but since there is no Submit, how do I call a query that will delete them afther that?

Comment: Delete? It is another question :) But... Do you want to delete them from page instantly on button click or after refresh?

Comment: But this is really another question :)

Comment: "Afther that I want the user to be bale to submit their selection and that will then delete the selected records."   So what I want is when I have displayed them, the user will select one or more, and then they will click a "delete" button and that will run a php script that will delete them from the database.

Comment: Hi Vladislav, I don't want to delete the deleted data from the page, I just want to delete the data assoisated with the checkboxes from the database, and i'm gonna redirect the user to the next page. I don't want to use ajax at all, and your code is too complicated for me to just figure out how the user can check a checkbox, click on a delete button and then delete the selected item from the database.

Comment: So just remove part, where divs are being deleted.

Comment: If you want to redirect, then do js redirect in success handler.

Comment: @user3565574 I edited my code. Tell me if you have some questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Sharikov's answer: You need to place the checkbox in the loop as he described, but if you want to be able to pass that info to another script, that works on the user input you need several more things:

```
echo "<form action='receiver.php' method='post'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo " <input type='checkbox' value='".$row['id']."' name='checkedBoxes[]'/> ".$row['Name'];
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='process'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then on receiver.php:

```
foreach($_POST['checkedBoxes'] as $box){
    $id = $box;
    //THEN DO SOMETHING TO EACH ID 
}
```

If you also want to see which boxes were unchecked, then things get a little more complicated because POST and GET will only pass the values of checked check-boxes. and there are several ways I can think of to do this. One way would be to  pass an array of the all ids displayed via a $_SESSION variable to the next script:

```
session_start();
$ids = new Array();
echo "<form action='receiver.php' method='post'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo " <input type='checkbox' value='".$row['id']."' name='checkedBoxes[]'/> ".$row['Name'];
    array_push($ids, $row['id'];
}
$_SESSION['ids'] = $ids;
echo "<input type='submit' value='process'>";
echo "</form>";
```

And then on receiver.php you can reference that array with $_SESSION['ids'] and compare it to the values that were checked. Just make sure you place session_start(); in your code to be able to see the variable!

Good Luck!

Comment: HI John. I tried out your code, but it doesn't do anything, It doesn't delete from the database.

Comment: You would add that code in where it says //do something to each ID here. You would have to do another query that goes something along the lines of `$sql = "DELETE FROM favourites WHERE id=" . $box;` But that is bad DB practice because most likely, what your deleting will contain a foreign key of another record, therefore breaking the link. Your DB may even throw an exception for this event based on your settings

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Sorry! Your answer is much more specific and thorough anyway! Mine is more general guidelines he could implement to fix the issue.

Comment: I figured out how to delet them, but it just deletes the last record, how do I make it delete all the checked ones? Thanks

Comment: If you place the DELETE query inside the for loop I place above it should delete all checked records. If I were debugging myself I would do `print_r($_POST['checkedboxes'])` and the beginning of the script. This will print the array so you can make sure the value are stored in it. If the array looks correct then make sure you have the for loop set up properly. If all the values are not correctly in the array, then I would check back to the script with the form in it. Make sure the checkbox input has the correct name attribute. `name='checkedboxes[]'`

Comment: If you forget the [] after checked boxes only one value will be passes (this sounds like it may be your issue).